# Analytic continuation of Complex contour

Tags: complex-analysis, rotations

In attached figure, $\psi_{\mp}(z)\sim e^{\mp az^4}$, where $z \in \mathbb{C} $and $a> 0$. These two function go to zero at $\infty$ in regions( shaded and unshaded Stokes sectors) as shown in that figure.

Now let $a=\rho e^{i \theta}$, and  allow rotation from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi$, but centre of shaded region, i.e., line  $~Im(z)=0$, gets rotated Anticlockwise by $\theta=\pi/4$, to the centre of Unshaded region, i.e., $Re(z)=-Im(z)$, why not in clock-wise direction ??

If I am able to express problem, then can anyone help me in that??

Basically it is about analytical continuation of $\psi_{-}(z)\sim e^{- az^4}$, from $a$ to $-a$

[One can see the Eq. 11 to 14. of this paper for better understanding of Ques](https://ac.els-cdn.com/037596019390153Q/1-s2.0-037596019390153Q-main.pdf?_tid=671b1f5b-b893-4f0f-9011-d35ac66bac6e&acdnat=1520337266_e1a4c73209bc896eb6f94a4c9ff0ad55)[image: One can see the For actual Text, one can seen Eq. 11 to 14. of this paper for better understanding of Ques]

Comment: What mean "vanish"? And the phrase "allow Clock-wise rotation... " is utterly incomprehensible.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Edited :) thank you

Comment: I think this might be the same confusion as the classic "when I compare the plots of f(x) and the plot of f(x+1) why does the graph move to the left instead of to the right ?"